# JasperReports: Headers Not In The Same Line

Tags: jasper-reports

The header of the report consists 10 elements it should look like this:

```
|1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10|
|--------------------|
```

In reality it look like this:

```
|1 2          8 9 10|
|---3 4 5 6 7 ------|
```

Is this something to do with the *verticalAligment*? I have set it to Bottom.

The snippet from my jrxml file:

```xml
<pageHeader>
    <band height="0"  isSplitAllowed="true" >
    </band>
</pageHeader>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="39"  isSplitAllowed="true" >
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement
                x="0"
                y="1"
                width="780"
                height="30"
                backcolor="#999999"
                key="rectangle-1"/>
            <graphicElement stretchType="NoStretch"/>
        </rectangle>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement
                x="0"
                y="0"
                width="40"
                height="30"
                key="staticText-1"/>
            <box></box>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
        <text><![CDATA[Holder Id]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement
                x="40"
                y="0"
                width="50"
                height="30"
                key="staticText-2"/>
            <box></box>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
        <text><![CDATA[Shell Id ]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement
                x="100"
                y="1"
                width="50"
                height="30"
                key="staticText-3"/>
            <box></box>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
        <text><![CDATA[Product Id]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement
                x="160"
                y="1"
                width="40"
                height="30"
                key="staticText-4"/>
            <box></box>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
        <text><![CDATA[SPID]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement
                x="200"
                y="1"
                width="40"
                height="30"
                key="staticText-5"/>
            <box></box>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
        <text><![CDATA[Loc-
ation]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement
                x="300"
                y="1"
                width="50"
                height="30"
                key="staticText-6"/>
            <box></box>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
        <text><![CDATA[Date]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement
                x="350"
                y="1"
                width="30"
                height="30"
                key="staticText-7"/>
            <box></box>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
        <text><![CDATA[Normal Fare]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement
                x="380"
                y="1"
                width="30"
                height="30"
                key="staticText-8"/>
            <box></box>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
        <text><![CDATA[Actual Fare]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement
                x="410"
                y="1"
                width="40"
                height="30"
                key="staticText-9"/>
            <box></box>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
        <text><![CDATA[Currency Code]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement
                x="450"
                y="1"
                width="30"
                height="30"
                key="staticText-10"/>
            <box></box>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
        <text><![CDATA[Staff Id]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement
                x="250"
                y="1"
                width="40"
                height="30"
                key="staticText-11"/>
            <box></box>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
        <text><![CDATA[Dest-
ination]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement
                x="750"
                y="0"
                width="30"
                height="30"
                key="staticText-12"/>
            <box></box>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
        <text><![CDATA[ISAM Seq.]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement
                x="700"
                y="0"
                width="50"
                height="30"
                key="staticText-13"/>
            <box></box>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
        <text><![CDATA[ISAM Id]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement
                x="670"
                y="0"
                width="30"
                height="30"
                key="staticText-14"/>
            <box></box>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
        <text><![CDATA[Trans. Type]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement
                x="630"
                y="1"
                width="40"
                height="30"
                key="staticText-15"/>
            <box></box>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
        <text><![CDATA[CPICC]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement
                x="510"
                y="1"
                width="30"
                height="30"
                key="staticText-16"/>
            <box></box>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
        <text><![CDATA[Conc. Auth]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement
                x="480"
                y="1"
                width="30"
                height="30"
                key="staticText-17"/>
            <box></box>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
        <text><![CDATA[Suppl. Info.]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement
                x="540"
                y="1"
                width="40"
                height="30"
                key="staticText-18"/>
            <box></box>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
        <text><![CDATA[Trans. Seq. No]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement
                x="580"
                y="1"
                width="40"
                height="30"
                key="staticText-19"/>
            <box></box>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
        <text><![CDATA[Rem. Uses]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</columnHeader>
```

Comment: can you show us some snippet from your jrxml?

Comment: @shanyangqu Why did you add the **dynamic-jasper** tag? Are you using Java code?

Comment: @AlexK there isn't clear rule on which tag people should using, dynamic-jasper != jasper report, but they are closely related, people who has the knowledge of dynamic-jasper is likely to help as well, hope this making sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried the stretch type, position type, flot etc.... bottom, asTallest, all sort of thing, it seems nothing worked

what I did was

- to change the height of the  which around all me header ReportElements from 39 to 20
- and each  height from 30 to 15
- increase some  width, make sure they are wide enough

the height 15 kind of forced the texts to stay in one line, give them no space to float,
I feel its a kind of ugly fix, my instinct tells me it must not be the greatest solution, but it works and I need finish it by today. free to post answers, I will accept yours if it works, and much more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your JRXML file, the best guess would be one (or combination) of two things:

- You do not have the vertical alignment set to `Bottom` for the fields 1,2,8,9,10.
- You do not have the same height set for 1,2,8,9,10.

In addition to those two, you do not have the tops set at the same `Top` value set for all the elements. Again this is all a best guess without being able to see your JRXML. If it is not one of those you will need to post it, so we can help.

Comment: nah, all set to bottom, but great stuff @jschoen , my 1st approach was to tweaking the flags and attributes, didn't work, then I tried with height, it worked, but not very nice.

Answer (score 0):

please see the Y Position. It is not same for all heading. you give Y position 0 for 1, 2, 8, 9, 10 and y=1 for remaing item. please make sure all position is same.